# Translating the "Everything" filter menu in Quicksand jquery file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, translation, plugin-polylang

I have been using QuickSand Jquery to display my WordPress portfolio.
Everything is working well. I just added the polylang plugin and would like to be able to translate the first item of the filter when I switch my page from en_GB to fr_FR.

I got this line in the file.js

```
// Creating the "Everything" option in the menu:
createList('View All',items);
```

I know I cannot mix php and js...
Is there a way to modify 'View All' by 'Tous' when the page is in French?

The idea was to do this:

```
if(pll_current_language() == 'en_GB'){
createList('View All',items);
} else {
createList('Tous',items);
}
```

But of course, it doesn't work at all.
Any idea to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: You've only included a line or two here so this is pure guess work but you could obtain the language of the page when the scripts are being enqueued and then pass that as a variable to JS (info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)... ...then you can check the language in JS. I'll try to add an answer but you'll have to modify if because you haven't included much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the language across using `wp_localize_script()`.

So you're obviously enqueuing your own custom javascript file, lets say that file is called `createlist.js`.

I assume you're doing it like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'createlist', plugins_url( 'createlist.js', __DIR__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```

(You'll need to adjust the path for the JS file based on where you have it, if this is in a theme or a plugin, do you have sub-directories, etc.

Immediately after that you'll want to also do something like:

```
if( !empty( $post ) ) :
    //research how to run a conditional check for PolyLang being active
    wp_localize_script( 'createlist', 'createlist_object',
        array(
            //pll_get_post_language( $post_id, $field ); - this is what you need
            'currentLang'       => pll_get_post_language( $post->ID, 'slug' ) //assuming that's how it works
        )
    );
endif;
```

In the above section, I'd also recommend you look into PolyLang and see if the documentation recommends a class you can look for to see if it exists before you try to retrieve a language, you should only execute functions that are plugin dependent IF that plugin is active.  So you'll need to look into that too.  Don't write code that assumes that something will ALWAYS be the case.

Now in your javascript file you'll want to retrieve what we just localized like so:

```
// First we get the current language we localized when the script loaded
var currentLang         = createlist_object.currentLang;
console.log( currentLang ); //so you can test and see which is which
// Now we check that variable against potential options
if( currentLang == 'en_GB' ) {
    createList( 'View All', items );
} else if( currentLang == 'fr_FR' ) {
    createList( 'Tous', items );
} else {
    // always include a fallback incase nothing is found or nothing matches
    createList( 'View All', items );
}
```

You'll have to run some tests though because I don't know which field value gives you what when using `pll_get_post_language( $post_id, $field )`...

*‘$field’ => (optional) either ‘name’ or ‘locale’ or ‘slug’, defaults to ‘slug’*

No clue which of those will spit out `en_GB` and `fr_FR` so test thoroughly. (This is why I added the `console.log( currentLang );` to the JS, comment that out or delete it once you figure out which field you need.

I think that covers it, best of luck.

Oh, here's the PolyLang link:
https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/